# What is a double dissolution election (Australia)

Tags: political-system, australia

Double dissolution elections are talked about in the media. What are they and how do they differ from normal elections?

Comment: It's *dissolution*, not disillusion.

Comment: @cpast why didn't you propose an edit?

Comment: It's the political equivalent of "Have you tried turning it off and on again?"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wikipedia states that since Australia has both a Senate and a House of Representatives, an election can be called if the two houses deadlock over a piece of legislation.

Normally only six of the twelve seats for each state  in the Senate are up for election. In a double dissolution election, all twelve seats are contested.

[Double dissolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dissolution)

> A double dissolution is a procedure permitted under the Australian
>   Constitution to resolve deadlocks between the House of Representatives
>   and the Senate. If the conditions (called a trigger) are satisfied,
>   the Government can request the Governor-General to dissolve both
>   houses of Parliament and call a full election. If, after the election,
>   the legislation that triggered the double dissolution is still not
>   passed by the two houses, then a joint sitting of the two houses of
>   parliament can be called to vote on the legislation. If the
>   legislation is passed by the joint sitting, then the legislation is
>   deemed to have passed both the House of Representatives and the
>   Senate. A double dissolution is the only circumstance in which the
>   entire Senate can be dissolved.

[Double Dissolution election](http://www.news.com.au/national/politics/explainer-what-a-double-dissolution-means-for-you/news-story/a8d3e7762ad75a66bd1461092e84d45b)

> Although it’s not a word that’s really used much in real life —
>   dissolution — in a parliamentary sense, simply means to dissolve a
>   house of parliament. That’s what happens when it’s time for an
>   election and the Governor-General, on the advice of the Prime
>   Minister, dissolves the House of Representatives, usually at the end
>   of its three-year term.
>
> A double-dissolution means dissolving both the upper and lower house,
>   essentially ending the reign of both the House of Representatives and
>   the Senate, and vacating each of those parliamentary representative’s
>   positions.